# How to store a class reference and compare it with an instance in swift?

Tags: swift, introspection

I want to store a reference on a type to compare it later with an object.

I tried to do:

```
let myClassRef = AClass.self // store a reference to the type of AClass
if myObject is myClassRef {
    // Do something
}
```

But it just does not work. How to use a AnyClass object ?
Alternatively, how to get an AnyClass object from an instance (this produce the same result as what I am expecting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `Aclass` subclass of `NSObject` & use `isMemberOfClass()`

```
let myClassRef = AClass.self // store a reference to the type of AClass

if myObject.isKindOfClass(myClassRef) {
// Do something
}
```

Comment: It does compare "Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIViewController>"
to 
"Optional(itooch_messenger.SearchUserViewController)"
Thus the comparaison is always false. Is there a way to get the real type ?

Comment: Make your class, subclass of 'NSObject'

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess swift has still some progress to make on the introspection front. Beware of `isKindOfClass` vs `isMemberOfClass`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to subclass `NSObject` you could use `dynamicType`:

```
let myClassRef = AClass.self

if myObject.dynamicType === myClassRef {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In this case, I compare Uiviewcontrollers so it's ok. +1 for the === maybe that's what I missed!

Comment: this will only test if the object's type is exactly that; not a subclass thereof

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to subclass `NSObject`.

If `myObject` is type `AnyObject`, you can just do this:

```
import Foundation

let myClassRef = AClass.self
let myObject : AnyObject = BClass()
if myObject.isKindOfClass(myClassRef) {
    // Do something
}
```

If `myObject` is a specific class or interface type, you can just cast it to `AnyObject` first:

```
import Foundation

let myClassRef = AClass.self
let myObject = BClass()
if (myObject as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(myClassRef) {
    // Do something
}
```